# Django-oscar demo error Can't import profile model

Tags: python, django, django-oscar

I downloaded django-oscar and i tried to run demo in the application. When i try to run demo, iam getting the error as 'Can't import profile model'. Urls.py file in this demo as

```
from apps.app import application
from datacash.dashboard.app import application as datacash_app
from oscar.views import handler500, handler404, handler403

admin.autodiscover()

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

    # Stores extension
    (r'^stores/', include(stores_app.urls)),
    (r'^dashboard/stores/', include(dashboard_app.urls)),

    # PayPal extension
    (r'^checkout/paypal/', include('paypal.express.urls')),

    # Datacash extension
    (r'^dashboard/datacash/', include(datacash_app.urls)),

    (r'', include(application.urls)),
)
```

Please suggest me some ideas to rectify this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE` setting? It should be a dotted path to a Model class. Can you import it in a python shell?

Comment: AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'user.Profile' This is the auth profile setting in my demo settings.

Comment: Can you do `from user import Profile` on a Python shell?